# Analyzing large amount of numbers using Python

Tags: python-3.x, sorting, random, count, numbers

I just start to learn programing using Python...

I need to analyze large amount of random numbers in Python... 108 000 to be exact.

Need to put them in a list and count for how many times number appears, they are in range 1-80...

What would you do in my situation and how to approach to that problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `groupby` function can help. https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby

```
>>> import itertools
>>>
>>> [(k, len(list(g)))  for k, g in itertools.groupby(sorted('cbcaaa'))]
[('a', 3), ('b', 1), ('c', 2)]
```

You could do the same with a bunch of `sorted` random numbers.

But there's a better way.

Since you have lots of input values but a very small number of possible outputs, consider allocating eighty counters:

```
from collections import defaultdict

cnt = defaultdict(int)
for num in random_nums:
    cnt[num] += 1
```

Comment: First of all, thanks that you take some time to answer me and help me, i will try that :)